# Get UserId from class library project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ip-address, class-library, userid

Is there a way to get the UserId from a class library project? This class library project logs everything a user does and write it to a database.

But I need the UserId too which I can't get from any project except a web project. I also would need the user's ip address from the class library project.

Anyone has done this before in an `asp.net-mvc` project and could share it how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar situation in my current project, the way I did it was to pass the UserID as a parameter from the MVC project into any method I used in the class library.

**EDIT**

```
public int ClassLibraryMethod(your parameters, **string userId**){}
```

Now from whatever class you are working from in your MVC project, you can call User.Identity.Name, assign it to a variable, and pass it along through your class library methods for use.

```
string userId = User.Identity.Name;

var lib = new ClassLibrary();
lib.ClassLibraryMethod(your data here, userId){}
```

This will allow you to get the userId from the MVC project through your methods.

Comment: Thought that wasn't possible because it's stateless. I did it in a similar way, but saved the userid in a `static` from a class library project that gets referenced by all other projects and that worked!