# MVC 5 HttpContext.User in data project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5, asp.net-mvc-5, httpcontext

I have a Solution with three projects organized like this:

Data(entity framework) -> Service -> Web (MVC).

**How can i get current loget User in my Data project from HttpContext in Controller?** I need to set columns in DB like CreatedBy and ModifiedBy then creating/editng item. (authentication mode is "forms")

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found the solution. I have created a base Service class where added constructor with User parameter and then assigned to all Services the my base Service class.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here. [Get UserId from class library project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23444366/get-userid-from-class-library-project/23451891#23451891)

Pretty much the same thing. In your MVC controller, create a variable and store the user name like this - `string user = User.Identity.Name;`

Then just add a parameter to whatever methods you need the user for in your data project, and pass the user variable along to your methods.

Comment: Do I understand you well? 
But this solution isn't good, because I now have about 1000 methods. I need to get user in my Entity overrided SaveChenges() method, to set fields ModifiedBy and CreatedBy. 
SaveChanges() mehod will set My fields for all tables automatically.

Becouse in your solution I must set those fields by hand for all creates or saves. 
And imagine 1000 methods and 2 fields it will be 2000 code lines :)

Comment: @MantvydasOzerenskis Yes, the way I suggested won't work for so many methods, well it would but it's far from the best way. Can you post your SaveChanges() method?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a static class which is reusable anywhere.

```
    public static class GetUserName
    {
        public static string Name(IPrincipal user)
        {
            return user==null? HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name:user.Identity.Name;
        }
    }
```